# Firewall rules to allow Hyper V Manager to connect to Hyper V Server 2012 R2?

Tags: group-policy, hyper-v, windows-firewall

I moved a Hyper V host into our Servers OU in Active Directory, which has some group policies linked.  Now I am unable to connect to the Hyper V host with Hyper V manager.  It was working fine before I moved the computer account in AD, so it must be a conflict with one of the group policies linked there.   So two questions:

Is there a way to roll back changes that have been applied by group policy?

Is there a rule, or set of rules, that I can enable in order to allow the Hyper V Manager to connect again?

Comment: `1.` I'm assuming you mean that you can't connect to the Hyper-V host using Hyper-V manager remotely. `2.` Have you looked at the GPO's being applied? Have you run GPRESULTS against the Hyper-V host? `3.` Have you looked at the firewall rules on the Hyper-V host? `4.` Have you tried moving the Hyper-V host back to it's original location and running gpupdate /force?

Comment: It was either the group policy that allowed remote desktop connections, or enabled file and printer sharing and ping.  I had changed the subnet of the remote PC after adding some VLANs, and both those policies were configured to only allow from the original subnet.